# to allow the user to input a 3-digit number, and then output the individual digits in the number

Tags: python

how would i allow a user to input a 3-digit number, and then output the individual digits in the number in python

e.g. If the user enters 465, the output should be “The digits are 4    6    5”

sorry if this sounds basic

Answer (score 1):

You use for your number `num`:

1. `num % 10` to extract the last digit.
2. `num = num // 10` to remove the final digit (this exploits floored division).

Finally, you want to get out the leading digit first. Therefore you adopt a *recursive* function to perform the above (which calls itself prior to printing the digit).

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `str.isdigit` and `re.sub` functions:

```
import re

num = input('Enter number:')
if num.isdigit():
    num_sequense = re.sub(r'(\d)(?=\d)', r'\1 ', num)
    print("The digits are:", num_sequense)
else:
    print("There should be only digits", num)
```

---

The output for the input `123`:

```
The digits are: 1 2 3
```

The output for the input `a1s2d3`:

```
There should be only digits a1s2d3
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to make in one line, anyway this should do exactly what you want:

```
inp = list(input())
print("The digits are ", end ='')
for i in inp:
   print(i, end=' ')
```

If you don't care for formatting, one-liner is possible:

```
print("The digits are ",list(input()))
```